# Zeppelin cannot import some classes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I created a new Notebook in Zeppelin and was able to import the following classes:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.LinearDataGenerator
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

However these two classes of Spark cannot be found by Zeppelin:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.TestSuiteBase
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you try adding spark streaming jar to $ZEPPELIN_HOME/lib ?

Comment: @Ashish: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/spark/target/lib`? I cannot find `lib` inside the root dicertory of `$ZEPPELIN_HOME`.

Comment: i'm not sure about your env, please try $ZEPPELIN_HOME/spark/target/lib as well